# CoreData loses relationship - only after reload

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am struggling with a problem since multiple hours - when I try to save some data to my CoreData - everything is fine, BUT when I restart my app, the relationship is lost.

It's an 1:n relation, the inverse relation is here (having multiple inverse relations, and all others are fine)

When I check with a sqlite-viewer, the chances are saved into the database, but when I reload the app, that 1 relation is gone.

There is also another question here, BUT: the solution did not work for me (and it seems that the solution not works for everybody) - and its 3+ years old.

Thanks in advance

Here is more information. The relation is between TaskCraft and Craft, like in this picture:

[image]

My CoreData Objects Are:

```
TaskCraft

    @NSManaged var taskcraft: [TaskCraft]?

Craft

    @NSManaged var craft: Craft?
```

My options:

[image]
[image]

Ill can reproduce the error all the time: When ill save the data to CoreData, my database look like:

[image]

When ill reload my app, and there is any CoreData-Fetch, my DB look like:

In this fetch i do not modify any of that NSManagedObjects.

[image]

Comment: You need to add more detail about what exactly your code does. There's no typical, common thing that makes Core Data just "lose" relationships.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, ive added some more information.

Comment: That just shows how the relationship is declared, but not how your app handles it. If you're losing relationships you might be failing to set them correctly, or failing to save changes, or setting them but accidentally wiping them out, or maybe something else.

Comment: It is saved, its in my database when ill check during save (in the simulator) - so all changes should be saved correctly or? When ill reload my App (and ill do no changes on start) and ill check my database again - that 1 relation is gone. If there is any problem with saving, WHY is that in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok problem solved for me. Ill created (by Xcode) all the NSManagedObjects again, changed all NSSets to the real class names, deleted the simulator cache, and tried again.

Now it works fine, no relation is dropped anymore.

Very strange, but i am happy now.